# How to make an image semi-transparent in Adobe Flash Professional?

Tags: adobe-flash, animation, transparency

I'm trying to animate a transition from one image to another in Adobe Flash Professional CS3. To do so, I want to put images one above another and animate transparency over time. But where do I find transparency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before changing transparency, an object, be it image, or text, or something else, must be converted to a symbol. Right click it and select "Convert to symbol", then click on it, select "Alpha" in the Color dropdown box and set any alpha that needs be.